# Why doesn't the local configuration for meta title and description override the global configuration | Nuxtjs | SEO meta

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-meta

I am working on a Nuxtjs project where I want to add SEO meta tags in the  section of the document.
According to the [official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/), there are three ways to achieve this.

**Problem** - The local configuration is not picked if there is a global configuration available. I expected that global settings are using for pages where I didn't specify the head object or function. and If I specify the head option then it should override the default(i.e global)

***Code part***

I have set the global configuration using nuxt.config.js as follow

***nuxt.config.js***

```
export default {
  // ...
  head: {
    title: 'my website default title',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: 'my website default description'
      }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
  }
}
```

and for my test page, I use the local configuration as follows

***test/index.vue***

```
export default {
    name: 'test-page',
    head() {
        return {
            title: 'Test page',
            meta: [
                {
                    hid: 'test-description',
                    name: 'test-description',
                    content: 'Test page description'
                }
            ],
        }
    },
}
```

But when I visit the test page, the title of the web page is showing as "my website default title" but I want to show "Test page".

If I remove the global configuration from the nuxt.config.js then it works fine. but for the page where I don't have the head option, it will not include the SEO meta tags for them.

Comment: Not sure where but IIRC, the Nuxt config file does have priority over local settings. Maybe needs a double-check on this far souvenir.

Comment: I found the issue. There was actually issue with titleTemplate which I didn't specify in my question. But actually I was using that and which includes the static string.